# Block one component getting CSS from another component angular6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component named `profile-data.component` that uses Angular Material `mat-tab-group` component, i used this Angular Material component in `tournament-list.component` first.

Now my `mat-tab-group` inside `profile-data.component` is getting the css from the `tournament-list.component` is there any way to block this?

My folder structure looks like this.

```
app
  profile
    profile-data
      profile-data.component

   tournament
     tournament-list
       tournament-list.component
```

This is my `profile-data.component.css`

```
.acc-settings{
   border-radius: 25px;
   display:inline-block;
   font-size: 30px;
   background-color: blue;
   color:white;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
 }
 .line {
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .mat-tab-body-content{
    color: blue;
  }
```

And my `tournament-list.component.css`

```
.mat-tab-body-content{
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And I am getting the color white instead of the blue

Comment: pls add your profile-data.component css or scss, usually the problem is that you can't override the material style, so, your issue sound really strange to me, sorry

Comment: Thanks for response, i've added css from both component

Comment: this didnt work, thats fine thanks for the help, get some rest.

Comment: What kind of view encapsulation are you using in your components? Can you show a DOM example of usage and of the component structures. Are the tab component part of the custom components (template) or content added to the custom components?

Comment: in `profile-data.component` i got the `mat-tab` inside the `mat-tab` i render `<app-tournament-list>` from the `tournament-list.component` @G.Tranter

Comment: That isn't very clear and doesn't answer all my questions. Post your templates and complete usage example(s). Where I'm going with this is that what you are trying to do should not have the problem you are having, therefore you must be doing something out of the norm that you haven't yet revealed.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewEncapsulation - Scoping Your Styles in Angular With ViewEncapsulation When set to Native - This is the encapsulation mode that would be ideal and it uses the Shadow DOM to scope styles only to that specific component.

In your component decorator use this property as follows:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
```

Comment: Didn`t work, and also i´m rendering more components, and doing this removed the css from the other components.